# Is it a sensible way of doing this by calculating array results?

Tags: java, arrays, count

First of all, this is a java dice throwing application. It will allow two players to play together as well as setting the number of dices for the throws. And from there, the results will be compared. Therefore, I will need to be able to count the number of 1 thrown by player one and subsequently player two.

Right now, my code is only catered for player one and from there, I shall add onto player two coding so as to not confuse myself. I have reached the part whereby I can count the number of 1 and 2 from the results but am not sure whether it is a feasible or sensible way of doing it(if-else) statement. I'm wondering if switch statement is possible or maybe perhaps any loops so could you guys give me some advise?

Thanks in advance!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

class TestDie {

public static void main (String [] args)
{
    Die firstDie = new Die();
    int[] playerOneResults;

    firstDie.roll();
    System.out.println(firstDie.getFaceValue());

    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("PLease enter the name of player one");
    String playerOneName = userInput.next();

    System.out.println("Please enter the name of player two");
    String playerTwoName = userInput.next();

    System.out.println("Enter the number of dice to be thrown");
    int numDice = userInput.nextInt();

    System.out.println("First player's name: " + playerOneName);
    System.out.println("Second player's name: " + playerTwoName);
    System.out.println("Number of dice will be thrown: " + numDice);

    playerOneResults = new int[numDice];
    int c = 0;
    int d= 0;

    for(int counter = 0; counter != numDice; counter++)
    {

        firstDie.roll();
        playerOneResults[counter] = firstDie.getFaceValue();
        System.out.println("Player one results: " + playerOneResults[counter]);

        if(playerOneResults[counter] == 1)
        {
            c++;
        } else if(playerOneResults[counter] == 2)
        {
            d++;
        }   

        System.out.println(c);
        System.out.println(d);  
    }







}
}
```

Comment: Why did you write a `Die` class, instead of using `1+Random.nextInt(6)`?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch oh it's a homework and i just follow as required. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be more elegant to use an array instead of the c and d variables :

```
int[] counts = new int[6];
for(int counter = 0; counter != numDice; counter++)
{
    firstDie.roll();
    playerOneResults[counter] = firstDie.getFaceValue();
    System.out.println("Player one results: " + playerOneResults[counter]);
    counts[playerOneResults[counter]-1]++;
}
```

counts[0] would hold the number of ones.
counts[1] would hold the number of twos.
...
counts[5] would hold the number of sixes.

Comment: hi there so do you mean the counts array will store the number of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6? thanks!

Comment: @alan_ogz83 Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: @alan_ogz83 I made a small fix, since I just realized the array indices are from 0 to 5 while the dice numbers are from 1 to 6.

Comment: wow it works! thanks so much bro but seriously, do you think you can tell me how does it work? especially the last sentence of coding. I don't get it how it works lol. cheers!

Comment: @alan_ogz83 the counts array has 6 integers. When it is created, they are all initialized by default to 0. counts[i]++ would increment the ith element of the array, which in our case is the number of times the dice result was i+1. That's why each time the dice give a result `playerOneResults[counter]`, we increment the `playerOneResults[counter] -1` int in the array.

Comment: thanks for explaining this to me but I still don't get it though lol.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56848/discussion-between-alan-ogz83-and-eran).

Comment: hey hi mate do you think we can chat so that i can ask you questions about the last line of code? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @alan_ogz83, I was away from my computer and way too busy yesterday to chat.

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming that you want to count how many times the die ends with 1,2,3...6 right? and have a variable for each of these? If that's the case i would do something like that

```
 int[] counts = new int[7];
    for(int counter = 1; counter <= numDice; counter++){
        firstDie.roll();
        playerOneResults[counter]; = firstDie.getFaceValue();
        counts[playerOneResults[counter]]++;
    }
```

I am using an Array of 7, skipping the element at 0, so that its easier for you to get the count for the 1 or 2 for example just by calling counts[1] or counts[2] etc.

Generally though you should split your code in methods. Not sure what your assignment requirements are but i don't see any reasons why you shouldn't.

Edit: Damn didn't notice Eran's answer. I am sorry.

Comment: hey hi George, do you think you could explain the purpose of the last line of code? I still don't get it. Thanks!

Comment: ok so. the counts Array holds 7 ints(0,1,...6). Once created it holds 7 zeros. We dont use the int at index 0 so we only care for 1 - 6. Every time you roll a die you add to the playerOneResults[counter] the facevalue. That can only be an int between 1 to 6. So everytime you have sych a value you go to the index in the counts array corresponding to that value and increase it by 1. For example if there is a 6 roll you go to counts[6] and increase its value by 1. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: thanks George! how about the one by Eran? there's a -1 involved which confuses me. Thanks!

Comment: oh btw George i think i do get wat yours mean just confused about Eran's lol.

Comment: Thats because Eran's loop starts at 0 and his array has 6 items. So if you get a 3 for example then you increase the 3rd element which is at index 2 in Eran's code(0,1,2). It's the same as mine, with the only difference that i skip the index 0 completely for convinience and i start from 1.